# Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have spend a whole week trying every method possible but I keep recreating the same error. I know that ngCordova.min.js must be above Cordova.js. But it seems nothing is loading my plugins. I visited ngCordova website and they explained that this error can be frustrating and hard to fix. Here are my files thank you

app.js

```html
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.directives','app.services','ngCordova'])

.config(function($ionicConfigProvider, $sceDelegateProvider){
  

  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([ 'self','*://www.youtube.com/**', '*://player.vimeo.com/video/**']);

})

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

/*
  This directive is used to disable the "drag to open" functionality of the Side-Menu
  when you are dragging a Slider component.
*/
.directive('disableSideMenuDrag', ['$ionicSideMenuDelegate', '$rootScope', function($ionicSideMenuDelegate, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",  
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            function stopDrag(){
              $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
            }

            function allowDrag(){
              $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
            }

            $rootScope.$on('$ionicSlides.slideChangeEnd', allowDrag);
            $element.on('touchstart', stopDrag);
            $element.on('touchend', allowDrag);
            $element.on('mousedown', stopDrag);
            $element.on('mouseup', allowDrag);

        }]
    };
}])



/*
  This directive is used to open regular and dynamic href links inside of inappbrowser.
*/
.directive('hrefInappbrowser', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    transclude: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var href = attrs['hrefInappbrowser'];

      attrs.$observe('hrefInappbrowser', function(val){
        href = val;
      });
      
      element.bind('click', function (event) {

        window.open(href, '_system', 'location=yes');

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

      });
    }
  };
});
```

controller.js

```js
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
  
.controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams) {


}])
   /*
.controller('scannerCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
function ($scope, $stateParams) {


}])
*/

.controller('scannerCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams',  function($scope, $rootScope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner, $ionicPlatform,stateParams) {




      $scope.scanBarcode = function() {
        $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
            alert(imageData.text);
            console.log("Barcode Format -> " + imageData.format);
            console.log("Cancelled -> " + imageData.cancelled);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
        });
    };
    }])
   

.controller('qRCodeCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams) {


}])

   
.controller('profileCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams) {


}])
      
.controller('signupCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams) {


}])
   
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams) {


}])
```

index.html (Template)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    
    
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    

    <style type="text/css">
      .platform-ios .manual-ios-statusbar-padding{
        padding-top:20px;
      }
      .manual-remove-top-padding{
        padding-top:0px; 
      }
      .manual-remove-top-padding .scroll{
        padding-top:0px !important;
      }
      ion-list.manual-list-fullwidth div.list, .list.card.manual-card-fullwidth {
        margin-left:-10px;
        margin-right:-10px;
      }
      ion-list.manual-list-fullwidth div.list > .item, .list.card.manual-card-fullwidth > .item {
        border-radius:0px;
        border-left:0px;
        border-right: 0px;
      }
      .show-list-numbers-and-dots ul{
        list-style-type: disc;
        padding-left:40px;
      }
      .show-list-numbers-and-dots ol{
        list-style-type: decimal;
        padding-left:40px;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    
     
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
     
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    

    <!-- Only required for Tab projects w/ pages in multiple tabs 
    <script src="lib/ionicuirouter/ionicUIRouter.js"></script>
    -->

  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
  <div>
  <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false" data-componentid="side-menu21">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
          <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
      </ion-nav-bar>
      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left" id="side-menu21">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <div class="title">Menu</div>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="menuCtrl" padding="false" class="side-menu-left has-header "></ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
  </ion-side-menus>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

scanner.html (Template)

```html
<ion-view title="Scanner" id="page2">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
   
  <div class="card">
            <div class="item">
                <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="scanBarcode()">
                    <i class="icon ion-qr-scanner"></i>
                    Scan Now
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

       
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Error satan wrote himself

```
0     801650   error    Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating   '$cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan')
scanBarcode@http://192.168.1.73:8100/js/controllers.js:26:31
fn
http://192.168.1.73:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65429:21
$apply@http://192.168.1.73:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30500:30
http://192.168.1.73:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65428:19
defaultHandlerWrapper@http://192.168.1.73:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16792:15
eventHandler@http://192.168.1.73:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16780:23
dispatchEvent@[native code]
triggerMouseEvent@http://192.168.1.73:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2953:20
tapClick@http://192.168.1.73:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2942:20
tapMouseUp@http://192.168.1.73:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:3018:13
```

[File Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Fp6.png)

Comment: Where is your code? or files?

Comment: sorry it uploaded before I was done @RaR

Comment: where is your controller?

Comment: I will add a screenshot @CarlosArauz

Comment: till I can't see your controller code, where is declared the function scanBarcode?

Comment: oops sorry fixed that @CarlosArauz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little bug on your code, you forgot to annotate $cordovaBarScaner.

```js
.controller('scannerCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope','$cordovaBarcodeScanner', '$ionicPlatform', '$stateParams',  function($scope, $rootScope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner, $ionicPlatform,stateParams) {




      $scope.scanBarcode = function() {
        $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
            alert(imageData.text);
            console.log("Barcode Format -> " + imageData.format);
            console.log("Cancelled -> " + imageData.cancelled);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
        });
    };
    }])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! I can't believe I can miss that small of an error!! I wish I could up vote you ten thousand times